# prove that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ exist then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

prove that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ exist then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$
So that's what I did so far 
Let $$B_{n}=\frac{(a_{2}-a_{1})+(a_{3}-a_{2})+...+(a_{n+1}-a_{n})}{n}=\frac{(a_{n+1}-a_{n})}{n}$$ and we know that if$\ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ exist that's mean that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}B_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$
Thus we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(a_{n+1}-a_{n})}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ But I don't know how to go from here

Comment: It should be $B_{n}=\dfrac{(a_{n+1}-a_{1})}{n}$, and then the result follows easily.

Comment: Oh yeah I see my bad there thank you

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule or [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the limit

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\tag 1$$

We assume that $L$ is finite.

From $(1)$, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N$ such that whenever $n>N$,

$$|a_{n+1}-a_{n}-L|<\epsilon/2 \tag2$$

With a given $\epsilon>0$ and corresponding $N$ fixed such that $(2)$ holds, we have (defining $a_0=0$)

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{a_{n}}{n} -L\right|&=\left|\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1}-L)\right|\\\\
&\le\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^{N}|a_k-a_{k-1}-L| +\frac1n \sum_{k=N+1}^n|a_k-a_{k-1}-L|\\\\
&\le \frac Nn \sup_{k\in[1,N]}|a_k-a_{k-1}-L|+\frac12 \epsilon\left(\frac{n-N}{n}\right)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

We can now take $n$ so that the first term on the right-hand side of $(3)$ is less than $\epsilon/2$.  And we are done!

Comment: Well your answer gave me another way to approach questions like that so I will say you already gave me the best answer Thank you

Comment: Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.